# How to check if elements in a sublist are strings?

Tags: python, list

```
lista = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]


def check(temp_plan):
    if all(isinstance(elements, str) for elements  in temp_plan):
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(check(lista))
```

I know the code above returns false since the elements in the list are lists.

Comment: what is wrong the code you posted? what output are you expecting?

Comment: @deadshot I am expecting that it returns True but my code is WRONG because it's looking in the list and not the sublists

Comment: You're going to have to look in the sublist. If you do not know the structure, search for "flattening" nested containers in python. Is that the real question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's *consistently* a two-dimensional list, then you can use a second `for` in the comprehension inside `all()`:

```
def check(temp_plan):
    return all(
        isinstance(e, str)
        for elements in temp_plan
        for e in elements
    )

print(check(lista))
# True
# since `isinstance(e, str)` is true for each sub-element
```

(note I replace `if all(...): True; else False` with just `all()`, since `all()` returns a `True` or `False` answer anyway).

Your condition `isinstance(e, str)` can be whatever you want - your question title says you want to check if they're integers, and if that's the case you can change the condition to `e.isdigit()`, which returns `True` if the string represents an integer and `False` otherwise.

Comment: That's it! You're a lifesaver! Ty!

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating the array `["a", "b", "c"]`, so `False` is no doubt the result when type-check with `str`

One solution is to flatten the n-dimensional array to 1-dimensional one and then check it (in the example I flatten the array using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain))

```
import itertools

lista = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]
listb = [[1, "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]

def check(temp_plan):
    if all(isinstance(elements, str) for elements in itertools.chain(*temp_plan)):
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(check(lista))
print(check(listb))
```

Comment: if clause is not needed. `all` returns true or false anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with `isinstance()` and `any()`:

```
>>> some_list = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", 5, "f"]]
>>> [any([isinstance(y, int) for y in x]) for x in some_list]
[False, True]
```

If you want to be more stringent, you can use `all()`:

```
>>> another_list = [["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> [all([isinstance(x, int) for x in y]) for y in another_list]
[False, True]
```

If you want to test all sublists, use `all()` again:

```
>>> all([all([isinstance(x, int) for x in y]) for y in another_list])
False
```

To turn that into a function:

```
def check(l):
  return all([all([isinstance(x, int) for x in y]) for y in l])
```

Comment: If your question has changed from integers to strings, replace `int` with `str` in the `isinstance` call.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that doesn't care about the internal structure. We can just check each element to see if it is str (return True), iterable (check all of its elements), else return False

```
from typing import Iterable

def check(data):
    if isinstance(data, str):
        return True # recursion base case
    if isinstance(data, Iterable):
        return all(map(check, data))
    return False

if not check('a'):
    raise ValueError
if check(0):
    raise ValueError

lista = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]
listb = [["a", ["b", "c", 0]], [["d", "e"], "f"]]
if not check(lista):
    raise ValueError
if check(listb):
    raise ValueError

print ('passed')
```